# With using SpriteKit It dosen''t return right information while touching the screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, uitouch

I am using SpriteKit making  a game , but before it went all right , but recently after I make it more compliant , something  wrong just comes up.
I have a button on the left corner , and while I touch the button , It showed nothing , so after I print out the information while touch the screen , I just find that it returns nil of this area , not even return the background information , the texture is nil , but if I touch other area , all go fine ,the information is all fine . So what is wrong here , I don't understand.

Here are some code that I write in toucheBegan function

```
     let touchLocation = (touches as NSSet).anyObject()?.locationInNode(self)

    let targetNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation!)




    print(targetNode)
```

And the console return these
: name:'(null)' texture:['nil'] position:{0, 0} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{1136, 640} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00

It only happens on this button , I don't know why

The code that declare the button:

```
    goRightButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "GorightButton1")
    goRightButton.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    goRightButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width - 200, y: 0)
    goRightButton.name = "Right"
    goRightButton.zPosition = -8
    self.addChild(goRightButton)
```

if I run it on iPhone 6 , No buttons work at all! what happened ? if I run at iPod with IOS9 , It works fine .

Comment: Could you post the code you use to declare and place the button?

Comment: yes,  
        goRightButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "GorightButton1")
        goRightButton.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        goRightButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width - 200, y: 0)
        goRightButton.name = "Right"
        goRightButton.zPosition = -8
        self.addChild(goRightButton)

Comment: I am sorry , now I have done

Comment: even the user interactionEnable is true :( , I don't know whats wrong

Comment: Help, help; ( . never happened to me before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this line

```
goRightButton.zPosition = -8
```

Change `zPosition` to greater than zero, because there is `SKNode` witch have higher `zPosition` than your `goRightButton`

```
goRightButton.zPosition = 999
```

Comment: Its because there is one or more nodes on top of all your view. and you are touching that node

Comment: @happyzhang187 change zPosition to 999

Comment: It works!but how can let this kind situation not happen

Comment: And it is so wired , coz I have a go left button which has the same zposition ,but that one works:(

Comment: Thank you so much ,Darvydas:*

Comment: @happyzhang187 Then scene gets heavier some thing like this might happen. So always set zPosition to all your nodes.

Comment: strange!while I use iPhone6 , no buttons work at all!!!? How come?;( the iPhone 6 run IOS8 , before I use iTouch run IOS9 ,why this happen? ;(

Comment: @happyzhang187 what you mean by not working? 1. You press then and nothing happens 2. They are not added 3...

Comment: sorry,Darvydas,It washy fault , I have another SKNode whose alpha equal 0 , I didn't notice , Now I find out out ,I am sorry